# How to run a Qt application on a system where Qt is not installed?

Tags: qt, deployment, fedora, qtwebkit

I have made an application using QtWebKit, Qt4. I have the binary generated in Fedora 16. Now, I want to run that application on another PC (running some other Fedora version), where Qt is not installed. How can I package my Qt application so that it can run on a platform where Qt is not installed? Is there any command line utility as well as QtCreator utility to do so. I have tried "deploy all" command, but it didn't have any affect.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Installer with the Qt Installer Framework and just supply all needed shared libraries (Win/OSX) or compile statically. Under Linux there is always the problem between system-wide libraries or bundled libraries. The documentation https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment.html should give you a good start

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need to have access to the qt libraries, which are exactly the same version that you used to compile your application.

There are two options :

- link qt libraries statically
- create a RPM package (see [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) how)

Also check [Deploying Qt Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html).

Comment: Yup, I do understand static linking. But, is there any option in qt-creator or qmake to build the application statically.

Comment: add CONFIG += static and supply statically built Qt

Comment: It looks like statically building QT in linux is a bad option. A better approach might be rpm. But, it will not be simple I feel. Because then rpm needs to install the qt libraries on the /usr/lib path. Also, I am not sure whether elf will be compatible with it or not.

Comment: For rpm, I should know what libraries are required. This needs the internal knowledge of the supported qt libraries to be installed. This also not straight forward. I need to find out the direct, indirect libraries required for the application.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI You can install libraries in different directories, not necessary under `/usr/lib/`. Nobody said the process is simple. You can also provide source files, and not worry about installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're deploying using rpm, to systems where Qt 4 rpms are available, you don't need to do anything besides simply adding a dependency on the qt to your rpm's specfile. The user installing your package using `yum localinstall` will get the Qt dependencies automatically installed. That's the correct way of doing it - it will keep your package size small.

Of course you need a separate rpm build for every fedora/centos major version out there, but that's almost always a requirement.

If your package needs newer Qt version than the one provided by the platform packages, you can still make a specific version dependency (say qt >= 4.7.0) and have a readme that indicates that newer packages can be obtained from a 3rd party repository (epel etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For deployment under Linux I've used [Bitrock Installer Tool](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/).

The main thing before deploying is to check your dependencies. You can do that by using command:

> ldd appName | grep libQt

After that you'll see list of dependencies. You'll have to set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to let linker know where're your libraries. To do that:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

. means current directory

And after that:

```
./appName $*
```

After that you'll be able to use your executable with Bitrock Installer Tool.